# Anchor with target="_blank" inside iframe sometimes doesn't work in IE 8

Tags: html, internet-explorer, iframe, internet-explorer-8, anchor

I have an iframe with the following doctype:

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
```

Inside this iframe, there is an anchor that has the attribute `target="_blank"`.

I got complaints that when opened in Internet Explorer 8, sometimes the url is opened in that iframe itself (so, as if there were no target attribute).

And my questions are:

1. Does it have anything to do with my doctype?
2. If it does, how do I fix it?

Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This problem of IE8 preventing links from spawning if they have target="_blank" appears to be limited to corrupt installs of IE8.

More explanation on this problem can be found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1066841/target-blank-doesnt-work-in-ie8-running-ies-side-by-side-i-run-the-package-o)